# Can't stop programs from reducing the volume of other programs in Windows 10

Tags: windows, audio

I've been trying to look for solutions everywhere, but bump into same answers:
https://www.tekrevue.com/tip/windows-reducing-system-volume/
https://superuser.com/questions/74116/windows-7-lowers-applications-volume-automatically
https://superuser.com/questions/504004/windows-8-turns-program-sound-volume-down-randomly

And so on. I've tried to toggle the communication settings, restart PC (every time I need to restart it), reinstall audio drivers (losing audio for few days) and the problem persists. And its not even associated with a specific program:

> - Youtube (on Chrome)
> - Unity Editor
> - Any game (HS/LoL/...)
> - Almost any other full-screen program
> - Skype

Any one of these start running first, the others take a hit of about 50% in volume. After about 10 seconds, for example a youtube video ends, the foreground app regains volume (did not follow how 3 different programs together behave). These volume changes do not show up in volume mixer.

**My machine:**

> Lenovo Y50-70, with Realtek audio drivers (now I have 2 audio logos in
>   my toolbar).

**Rant:**

> This is beyond frustrating, besides other windows problems I'm having:
>   delayed scrollwheel in Chrome (if I don't scroll for a second), memory
>   warnings with 16 GB of RAM, toolbar not showing up with some windowed
>   fullscreen programs (mainly Chrome) and programs taking focus 3 times
>   during launch (Alt-Tab is a waste at that point).

I can adjust my habits with other problems, but I can't adjust audio of programs, in a way that would work every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the culprit: **Dolby Digital Plus**

1. Sound
2. Playback tab
3. Speakers (right click) Properties
4. Dolby tab
5. The circle "I/O button" actually toggles the effect

While its on, the computer might sound louder, but it does it only for a single program. Hence the initial problem.

The solution might seem trivial, but I couldn't find anything on it on the interned, and only now I tried the button itself (thought it was only a decoration before).

Comment: I don't know who you are but right now I love you in so many different ways I cannot even describe. This has been bugging me for YEARS! the same Y50-70 system as well! So many google searches... so many different keywords... so for anyone else looking for this for years, I'll put the keywords I looked for: realtek automatic volume adjust windows 7 windows 8 windows 8.1 focus teamspeak front application priority disable automatically

Answer (score 0):

I feel your pain. The only real help I've found is to use the Ear Trumpet utility created by Rafael Rivera and David Golden. You can get it from the Store for free.

Perhaps the source code could let you adapt it and create what you need if you're handy with `C#` coding.

An overview: [MSPowerUser announcement](https://mspoweruser.com/ear-trumpet-is-a-new-app-for-windows-10-which-brings-better-volume-contro/)

Source: [EarTrumpet on GitHub](https://github.com/File-New-Project/EarTrumpet)

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't help.